How can I improve my overall flexibility for Aikido?

Training in Aikido improves physical conditioning, and helps develop balance, flexibility and coordination. Falling down and getting up repeatedly during class teaches you the ability to easily regain equilibrium and develops physical resilience. Then, taking someone else’s balance provides you a study of connected yet independent movement, maintaining your balance while guiding a partner. 
Source

How can I improve my overall flexibility for Aikido?

Your Aikido school will have you do a number of flexibility and warm-up exercises at the start of each class and possibly at the end as well. Flexibility exercises will work on twisting and extending your wrist, elbow, shoulder, neck, back, hip, knee, and ankle joints. It will also work on your major muscle and tendon groups like the glutes, hamstrings, quads, traps, and lats. And during class, all of the things you do will actually be working on your flexibility to some extent, functionally. Your teacher may also encourage you to perform these stretches outside of class daily on your own time.
So, merely attending class often enough should allow you to make progress on your flexibility, or at least know what you need to work on outside of class.
Beyond that, you certainly can take a more general approach to flexibility training by doing something additional on your own time. Yoga is a good thing to look into. I did Taekwondo in my earlier years, and I have never been more flexible since. I've heard good things about Ballet. Gymnastics is good. Etc.
Online on YouTube, there are plenty of stretching programs. Each one may offer some stretches that you've never done before. The idea is to collect the ones you find interesting, and then work on them at home.
I also recommend buying a mat for working on your stretches at home or on the go. I like 2 inch foam mats, the kind that fold up, not the kind that you roll up. The dimension I like and use is 4 feet by 10 feet, folded into 4 sections of 4 feet by 2.5 feet. This can be folded up and taken with you in your car anywhere. You can even practice breakfalls on them.
Whatever you do, you should try to make stretching a daily practice. In fact, the thing I used to do when I was the most flexible I have ever been was to stretch several times a day. I would wake up in the morning and stretch a few minutes getting right out of bed. Then after breakfast, a full stretch routine lasting at least 15 minutes. Then mid-day sometime you do some stretching when you can, maybe 5 to 10 minutes. Then before class you stretch. Then after class you stretch. Before bed, do a little stretching.
It becomes habitual if you do it that way. When I was most flexible, I would take almost every opportunity to do a little stretching. Like if you're waiting in line somewhere, you can always flex your wrists every now and then with a kote-gaeshi hold on your hands. Or squat down and flex your hips. Spread your legs out in a split. Get up on the balls of your feet and wiggle your ankles. Stuff like that. It really does become a habit. And you won't like the feeling of not being flexible or not being "ready", if you know what I mean.
Hope that helps.
